# Importing data from one server to another generates wrong physical folders tree

Tags: 2011, publishing, content-porter-2009

I've setup a new server for my Tridion development and I've made a content import (with Content Porter) from the old one to the new one.

Everything seemed to work fine until I've tried to publish my first page, the publication went good but the page was physically created in a new (unwanted) folder which has the ID of the publication.

The page should be published in:

`$HOME$/gl_en/Homepage.aspx`

but the result is:

`$HOME$/gl_en/pub13/Homepage.aspx`

where `pub13` is the unwanted folder.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the configuration of your `cd_storage_conf.xml`, specifically the `<Storages>` element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error could have happening because in the cd_storage_conf.xml located in your deployer you have the defaultFileSystem and defaultStorage attributes set to true, change then to false, restart the deployer application and try again.

Comment: Thank you Eric! That was the point, it was always good explained here http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3392/published-file-is-not-being-copied